# R Shiny app compatibility in different OS?

Tags: r, linux, windows, shiny

I would like to develop an app which will operate locally in a server. At the moment, I don't know if the available server has a Linux distro or Windows OS. Also, I already know that some of the users use Ubuntu, while some others Windows. My questions are the following:

1. Is R optimized for all Linux distros or will I experience different
   behavior among them (in terms of resource management)?
2. Is there any chance to observe bugs depended to the OS used by the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R Shiny Server is only supported on Linux as far as I know. You can try to install it in a virtual machine on your windows though. Look some information about it [here](https://github.com/leondutoit/shiny-server-on-ubuntu).